# why x-axis showing alternate months rather every month?

Tags: highcharts

Following is my highcharts config, can you help me to why my alternate months are coming, and if i want to show every month, how do i do it ? Also, to change width of the bar if showing every month.

```
Highcharts.chart("energy_chart", {
            chart: {
              type: "column",
              spacingBottom: 15,
              spacingTop: 10,
              spacingLeft: 10,
              spacingRight: 10,
              backgroundColor: "#f2f2f2",
              events: {
                load: function() {
                  var fin = new Date();
                  var finDate = fin.getDate();

                  var finMonth = fin.getMonth();
                  var finYear = fin.getFullYear();

                  var ini = new Date();
                  ini.setFullYear(ini.getFullYear() - 1);
                  var iniDate = ini.getDate();
                  var iniMonth = ini.getMonth();
                  var iniYear = ini.getFullYear();
                  if (this.yAxis[0].dataMax == 0) {
                    this.yAxis[0].setExtremes(null, 1);
                  }
                  //this.yAxis.set
                  console.log(new Date(Date.UTC(iniYear, iniMonth, iniDate)))
                  console.log(new Date(Date.UTC(finYear, finMonth, finDate)))
                  this.xAxis[0].setExtremes(
                    Date.UTC(iniYear, iniMonth, iniDate),
                    Date.UTC(finYear, finMonth, finDate)
                  );
                },

                drilldown: function(e) {
                  console.log('drilldown')
                  var charts_this = this;
                  var inidrillDate = new Date(e.point.x);

                  setTimeout(function() {
                    inidrillDate.setDate(0);
                    inidrillDate.setMonth(inidrillDate.getMonth());
                    var DateinidrillDate = inidrillDate.getDate();
                    var MonthinidrillDate = inidrillDate.getMonth();
                    var YearinidrillDate = inidrillDate.getFullYear();
                    var findrillDate = inidrillDate;
                    findrillDate.setMonth(findrillDate.getMonth() + 1);
                    findrillDate.setDate(findrillDate.getDate() - 1);
                    var DatefindrillDate = findrillDate.getDate();
                    var MonthfindrillDate = findrillDate.getMonth();
                    var YearfindrillDate = findrillDate.getFullYear();
                    console.log(Date.UTC(
                      YearinidrillDate,
                      MonthinidrillDate,
                      DateinidrillDate
                    ))
                    console.log(Date.UTC(
                      YearfindrillDate,
                      MonthfindrillDate,
                      DatefindrillDate
                    ))
                    charts_this.xAxis[0].setExtremes(
                      Date.UTC(
                        YearinidrillDate,
                        MonthinidrillDate,
                        DateinidrillDate
                      ),
                      Date.UTC(
                        YearfindrillDate,
                        MonthfindrillDate,
                        DatefindrillDate
                      )
                    );

                    if (charts_this.yAxis[0].dataMax === 0) {
                      charts_this.yAxis[0].setExtremes(null, 1);
                    }
                  }, 0);

                }
              }
            },
            title: {
              text: '<p className="energy_gen">Energy Generated</p>'
            },
            exporting: { enabled: false },
            xAxis: {
              type: "datetime",
              labels: {
                step: 1
              },
              dateTimeLabelFormats: {
                day: "%e"
              }
            },
            yAxis: {
              title: {
                text: "kWh"
              }
            },
            credits: {
              enabled: false
            },
            plotOptions: {
              series: {
                cursor: "pointer",
                dataLabels: {
                  enabled: true,
                  format: "{point.y}"
                },
                color: "#fcd562",
                point:{
                  events:{
                    click:function(event){
                      }     
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            tooltip: {
              formatter: function() {
                if (this.point.options.drilldown) {
                  return (
                    "Energy generated: <b> " +
                    this.y +
                    "</b> kWh " +
                    "<br>" +
                    Highcharts.dateFormat("%b %Y", new Date(this.x))
                  );
                } else {
                  return (
                    "Energy generated: <b> " +
                    this.y +
                    "</b> kWh " +
                    "<br>" +
                    Highcharts.dateFormat("%e %b %Y", new Date(this.x))
                  );
                }
              }
            },
            series: [{'data':obj.data,'name':obj.name,"color":"#4848d3"}],
            drilldown: {
              series: obj.data
            }
          });
```

Also, attaching the screenshot of the rendered highchart with drilldown.

[image: graph1],

Now drilldown graph(same sort a issue)

[image: drilldown graph]

EDIT:

It turnsout to be a zoom issue, i.e if i zoomout enough, then it shows all points. So, how to show every point without zooimg out .

Working fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/gkumar77/w9ngp63u/5/

Comment: Hi Gaurav Kumar, Could you provide us with some minimal live example of this problem? (example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6m4e8x0y/)

Comment: @ppotaczek i added a fiddle for understanding, althogh second drilldown is not showing.

Answer (score 1):

Use `tickInterval` property and set it to one month:

```
        xAxis: {
          type: "datetime",
          tickInterval: 30 * 24 * 3600 * 1000,
          labels: {
            step: 1
          },
          dateTimeLabelFormats: {
            day: "%e"
          }
        }
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/q5coany2/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.tickInterval

Comment: first of all, thanks man. u r being very much helpful. Now, in tickInterval, it does'nt seems to be working for day wise drilldown. it works for months but not for drilldown.

Comment: Hi Gaurav Kumar, Please check this example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/9b0kv2Ly/, you should update the `xAxis` in drill-events to acheieve the wanted result.